# Yii2 change controller and action name acording to language selected

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible to change controller name and action name with current selected language like:

If current language is en then url shuold:

http://localhost/yii2app/site/index

and if current language is da then url should:

http://localhost/yii.../websted/indeks

> > It is what I have tried but it shows 404 not found:

frontend/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            Yii::t('app','site/index') => Yii::t('app','site/index'),
        ],
 ],
```

in common/messages/da/app.php

```
 return [
         'site/index'=>'websted/indeks'
 ];
```

In my layouts/main.php

```
  <a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager
                  ->createUrl([Yii::t('app','site/index')])?>">
      <?= Yii::t('app','Home') ?>
  </a>
```

Comment: You should try with https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls

Comment: No I don't want to put en,da in url :)

Comment: Then I would suggest to create your own Route class (a child class) to detect language and then apply the correct UrlRoute rule

Comment: Yeah, I'm searching how I can create my own Route class.

Comment: I think it fail because component `urlManager` run before `i18n` component. So you can set your rule at `bootstrap`.

Comment: That is my idea, but now I can't check or post answer. I will check it when I get home. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified this code from the Yii forum to work with the current framework version. It needs to be tested because I'm pretty sure not every case is covered there.

common\components\UrlManager.php:

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Request;
use yii\web\UrlManager as YiiUrlManager;

/**
 * UrlManager
 * Allows to translate urls dynamically.
 */
class UrlManager extends YiiUrlManager
{
    public $enablePrettyUrl = true;
    public $showScriptName  = false;

    public $language;

    /**
     * Translated controllers names.
     * language code => [
     *      source name => translated name
     * ]
     * @var array 
     */
    public $languageControllers = [
        'eo' => [
            'site'  => 'ejo',
            'users' => 'uzantoj'
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Translated actions names.
     * language code => [
     *      source name => translated name
     * ]
     * @var array 
     */
    public $languageActions = [
        'eo' => [
            'contact' => 'kontakton',
            'about'   => 'pri-ni',
            'test'    => 'testo'
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Initializes UrlManager.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        if (empty($this->language)) {
            $this->language = Yii::$app->language;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates translated url.
     * @param array $params
     * @return string the created URL
     */
    public function createUrl($params)
    {
        $params = (array)$params;

        $route = explode('/', trim($params[0], '/'));
        if (isset($route[0]) && !empty($this->languageControllers[$this->language][$route[0]])) {
            $route[0] = $this->languageControllers[$this->language][$route[0]];
        }
        if (isset($route[1]) && !empty($this->languageActions[$this->language][$route[1]])) {
            $route[1] = $this->languageActions[$this->language][$route[1]];
        }
        $params[0] = implode('/', $route);

        return parent::createUrl($params);
    }

    /**
     * Translates the request back to the source one.
     * @param Request $request the request component
     * @return Request
     */
    public function translateRequest($request)
    {
        if (empty($this->languageControllers[$this->language])) {
            return $request;
        }
        $url = ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $parts = explode('/', $url);
        $controller = $parts[0];
        $action = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : null;
        foreach ($this->languageControllers[$this->language] as $default => $localized) {
            if ($localized == $controller) {
                $controller = $default;
                break;
            }
        }
        $parts[0] = $controller;
        if ($action !== null) {
            foreach ($this->languageActions[$this->language] as $default => $localized) {
                if ($localized === substr($action, 0, mb_strlen($localized, 'UTF-8'))) {
                    $action = $default . substr($action, mb_strlen($localized, 'UTF-8'));
                    break;
                }
            }
            $parts[1] = $action;
        }
        $request->setPathInfo(implode('/', $parts));
        return $request;
    }

    /**
     * Parses and translates the user request.
     * @param Request $request the request component
     * @return array|boolean the route and the associated parameters. The latter is always empty
     * if [[enablePrettyUrl]] is false. False is returned if the current request cannot be successfully parsed.
     */
    public function parseRequest($request)
    {
        return parent::parseRequest($this->translateRequest($request));
    }
}
```

UrlManager configuration:

```
// ...
'components' => [
    // ...
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\UrlManager',
        // ...
    ],
],
```

Now, for Yii:$app->language = 'eo';

1. /site/test calls controller Site with action Test.
2. /ejo/testo calls controller Site with action Test.
3. /ejo calls controller Site with action Index.
4. /site/testo calls controller Site with action Test.

For different languages only existing routes work. You can send parameters to action in the normal way.

Comment: Thank you! your solution is good, I have tried same as you describe. What if I don't want to declare `$languageControllers` and `$languageActions` in this class, I want to use messages\app.php languages. 
Like `$route[0] = Yii::t('app','ejo')`

Comment: Easiest way is to use them anyway but with Yii::t like:

`public $languageControllers = [
        'eo' => [
            'site'  => Yii::t('app', 'site'),
            'users' => Yii::t('app', 'users')
        ],
    ];`

Comment: Got error ;) `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'` using this `public $languageControllers = [ 'eo' => [ 'site' => Yii::t('app', 'site'), 'users' => Yii::t('app', 'users') ], ];`

Comment: I don't know the exact issue but your solution is not working for me. Pretty Url's gone now. and in console I see this error: `TypeError: toolbarEl is null
var barEl = toolbarEl.querySelector(barSelector),`

Comment: I think issue is with baseurl `print_r($parts);
        Array ( [0] => yii2app [1] => controller-name ) , here is yii2app is project name not controller name and in `$controller = $parts[0];` yii2app value assigned to $controller

Comment: You are right, I've fixed the class - translateRequest() now operates on pathInfo instead of url.

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't run because when yii2 load your config, it don't have `Yii` instance.

I have 2 ideas for your problem. Hope it useful.

**1: Use `redirect`**

Example:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::$app->language === 'da')
        return $this->redirect(['websted/indeks']);
    else
        return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
}
```

When user request to `site/index`, yii will redirect to other link base on your language. Address in browser will change to `@baseUrl/websted/indeks` when language is `da`. But you must define and change your code whenever you have new language in your app.

**2. Set `rule` at bootstrap**

Config:

```
'bootstrap' => [
    'log',
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\Bootstrap',
    ],
],
```

Bootstrap.php

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface
{

    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        $app->urlManager->addRules(['site/test' => Yii::t('app','site/test')]);
    }
}
```

Language 1, `app.php`

```
return [
    'site/test'=>'site/test1',
];
```

Language 2, `app.php`

```
return [
    'site/test'=>'site/test2',
];
```

Controller(example `SiteController`):

```
public function actionTest1()
{
    echo 1;
}

public function actionTest2()
{
    echo 2;
}
```

But problem is: when user request `site/test`, yii will check language and run action `test1` or `test2`, and address in your browser is only `@baseUrl/site/test`.

[image]

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: Pls check this, it is perfect solution, however I'm unable to get it run. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68654-routes-based-on-language

Comment: Yeah, inherit `urlManager` and `Application` :)